# Start Google Chrome on Mac with command line switches

Tags: macos, google-chrome, arguments

I've [read](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=23145) you can start Google Chrome in kiosk mode in Windows by using the argument `--kiosk`.

I know how to do this on Windows, but how can I do this on Mac OS X?

And how can I run Google Chrome with the `--kiosk` argument on startup?

Comment: @YumYumYum ugh! It's 2017 and *none* of the answers work (anymore?)!

Answer (score 122, accepted):

This works with macOS:

```
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --kiosk
```

Comment: You mean the argument doesn't work? The actual process of full screening Chrome *is* in the Mac version. Any hack to send a Cmd+Shift+F to get it to full screen? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Ok. Can you try "ls /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS" (or something like that) and post that?

Comment: @Andrew I ran `ls /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS` and it printed 'Google Chrome' only. :S

Comment: Finished and edited answer. Try now.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for that, and how would I run this on startup? Cheers.

Comment: It does work for macOS Mojave 10.14.

Answer (score 36):

It is probably even better to use the `open` command (in case the application is not located in the Application folder). E.g.: `open -a "Google Chrome" --args --kiosk http://www.example.com`

Comment: It does work for macOS Mojave 10.14.

Comment: Second param is ignored :shrug:

Answer (score 11):

In AppleScript, paste the following text:

```
do shell script "/Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome --kiosk"
```

Save it as an application and add it to your startup items.

Comment: It did back in 2012. Now,  use the code that newer comments have mentioned, `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --kiosk --app=http://domain.com` put that in a plain txt document, but add the following snippet above the call to Chrome to make it executable,`#!/bin/bash ` and add it to your startup items, or doublbe click to launch.

Comment: @vynsynt, Is the binbash line really needed?

Answer (score 6):

You can create an alias to open websites or files via command line. To do this, you can include at the end of your `~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.aliases` the following lines:

```
# Google Chrome Alias
google-chrome() {
    open -a "Google Chrome" "$1"
}
```

Comment: This is not how you deal with spaces in filenames. Learn to quote or escape special chars properly.  Also, `"$1"` is not going to work right when you have more than one param to pass, especially if those params themselves have unquoted values.

Comment: Hi @Marcin! If you know how, could you improve my response? 

Comment: Good answer.  Won't let me edit unless I put in at least 6 characters (to change `"$1"` to `"$@"` since you're using bash specifically here).  Also probably best it's not in ~/.aliases really.  An alias would be something like `alias google-chrome='open -a "Google Chrome"'`