# Chrome Kiosk-mode in OS X Lion allows top menu bar?

Tags: google-chrome, osx-lion, kiosk

Using the information [here](https://superuser.com/questions/209980/mac-osx-start-google-chrome-in-kiosk-mode-error), I was able to place Chrome into Kiosk mode on OSX Snow Leopard. However, in Lion it *appears* to work but if you move the mouse cursor to the top of the screen, the menu bar and address bar appear, which eliminates the "kiosk mode" function.

I'd like to stay in kiosk mode all of the time, how can I obtain this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

As of August 2013 there's no fix for Lion (or, presumably, Mountain Lion):

http://my.opera.com/community/forums/topic.dml?id=1738642

"It would work as you expect in older versions of the operating system. It is very difficult to lockdown a Mac in the way you want. Too many things remain accessible to the user. Eg. Command–Shift–Option–Q or Command–Option–Eject/Power.

Reinstalling a Linux desktop will give you more control (and kiosk mode working as you want), but it is then again harder to maintain."

You may be able to make it behave as you wish by running it in kiosk mode in a user account with simple finder and single app enabled.