# How can I have multiple browsing sessions in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, osx-lion

I often need multiple browsing sessions for logging into multiple services with different accounts at one time. I don't want to have to use multiple browsers, nor do I want to use a different release of Google Chrome. I would be open to running multiple *instances* of Google Chrome. However, I've tried using `open -na Google\ Chrome` and it won't open a second instance. Is there a way to do this on a Mac with Google Chrome?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Chrome supports multiple user profiles, you can make use of this to have multiple browsing sessions.

Click on the Chrome Menu (Mac users: Chrome-Preferences) → Click on Add New User. Now, there's a new instance of Chrome with a entirely different profile from the current user, so the cookies and the like are not shared.

Now, when you launch a new window, you can select a user profile to switch between & hence have multiple sessions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Sorry it took me so long to accept. I forgot about the question :-)

Comment: @daviesgeek hehe, not a problem

Comment: +1 This answer perfectly solves my needs! Too bad I didn't know about this feature before...

Comment: For me, on a Mac, I had to choose the following from the menu: "Chrome | Preferences" then look for "Users" and click "Add New User", using Chrome Version 24.0.1312.52 ("Chrome | About Google Chrome")

Comment: @Sathya can you have multiple sessions (users) opened at the same time?

Comment: @Howie yes, that's possible.

Comment: Excellent! I was actually using Safari for my other profile, this Chrome option is much better!

Answer (score 7):

I don't know about the MAC, but

```
mkdir newProfile
chrome --user-data-dir=newProfile
```

Works great here on Linux!

Comment: And on osx `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --user-data-dir=my-profile-dir` (http://superuser.com/questions/157484/start-google-chrome-on-mac-with-command-line-switches)

Answer (score 2):

Found this marvellous solution: https://sites.google.com/a/yarina.org/dougs-notes/home/mac-os-x/multiple-instances-of-chrome

I would probably alter the solution a bit by having the `chrome` function point to a time stamped directory in `/tmp/`. That way a new instance could be created each time by typing in only `chrome` rather than `chrome /tmp/junk/`.

I've also been using http://watir.com/ which launches new Chrome instances. Would be nice to look into watir's source to see how they do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using an Incognito window.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used an incognito window, but I can't run more than two sessions at one time. I need several sessions open at one time.

Answer (score 0):

This one: http://techparade.blogspot.com/2011/03/multiple-user-profiles-in-google-chrome.html allows you to set up a full-fledged Application for multiple instances of chrome.

Comment: Avoid simply linking to the solution as links can sometimes disappear over time. Post an excerpt or key parts instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use google account for loggin in, then use this plugin
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/freshstart-cross-browser/nmidkjogcjnnlfimjcedenagjfacpobb?hl=en