# Any way to make google remember additional accounts in multiple sign-in?

Tags: google-chrome, google-workspace

Google multiple sign-in is handy, but whenever I reboot my computer I have to re-add all my accounts other than the default. Is there any way I can make it remember at least the account name? (I'm using Chrome 19)

Comment: Setting up multiple chrome local users may help you: http://superuser.com/q/415531/55796

Comment: that's handy for sure! I still want my bookmarks/extensions, though, so not quite what I'm after

Comment: BTW, the account name should be stored if you are saving passwords. If that's not happening then you may have a mis-configuration somewhere.

Comment: it's possible I may have accidentally told it not to remember that password.. do you know if there is a way I can go back and change that?

Comment: In Chrome 19 the option you are looking for is in `settings->show advanced settings->passwords and forms`. The specific names may be different.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using an extension like [LastPass](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm) which is a password manager and allows for multiple sets of authentication profiles.

[image]