# stop chrome from redirecting gmail.com to g suite admin page

Tags: google-chrome, gmail, google-search

This is pretty maddening, whenever I go to gmail.com I get immediately redirected to the g suite admin page.

But i just want to view person email not my work g suit admin page. So I go to gmail.com and switch to my personal account. At that point Im redirected to g suite admin and Im met with this error:

`admin.google.com is for G Suite accounts only. Regular Gmail accounts cannot be used to sign in to admin.google.com. Learn more`

What i have to do is go back to the google search page, switch accounts from there, then click the "gmail" link on the google search page to get to email

Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you tried the basics like clearing cache, cookies etc? Also have you modified your systems host file? Lastly, can you reproduce the issue on another browser? That will help narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the **private browsing mode of Chrome**, for your personal Gmail account.

It has many advantages:

- You don't mix personal and professional data
- Both will be in a separate window that you can minimize (you probably don't want a coworker to look at your emails, if you need to show him/her something on your browser)
- The private browsing mode will not use any active G Suite session
- When you close the private windows, your private Gmail will be disconnected. On a work computer, I believe it's a good practice.

---

**Edit:** if you want to keep the Gmail session open (with 2-factor authentication), you can use the Google Chrome profiles to keep both environments (work & private) separated.

[Everything is explained here](https://superuser.com/questions/415531/how-can-i-have-multiple-browsing-sessions-in-google-chrome).

Comment: I have set gmail to require security code for new devices which means Id have to do that every time I open inprivate browser- so this is not convenient

Comment: Inconvenient, yes; but a better practice on a work computer, IMO. If two Google active sessions (G Suite and Gmail) cohabit in the same environment, they'll bump into each other eventually. Using private mode prevents this, but won't remember 2-FA authorization, indeed.
the other alternatives would be to use a different browser, or a perhaps portable Google Chrome that lives on a USB key (not sure about that one).

Comment: @user1028270, I edited my post to include another solution that may suit your needs better!